# How to match the order of imported polylines in a shapefile (i.e.,"OBJECTID") to the order listed by NetLogo

Tags: netlogo, arcgis, shapefile

I used the location-of method in NetLogo to get Netlogo coordinates of respective ArcGIS polylines vertices. However, the order of the polylines ("OBJECTID" in ArcGIS) does not match the order listed by NetLogo's location-of method.

How can I match them? OR
How can I make NetLogo show the correct corresponding OBJECTIDs as those in ArcGIS?

[image]
[image]

Comment: never (on Stack Overflow, or anywhere on the internet) take screen shots of code. always copy and paste the actual code as text. screen shots aren't searchable and the code in them can't be copied and pasted in NetLogo. these barriers make helping you unnecessarily difficult.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of fput use lput in code line : 'set arealist fput (list location) arealist'